# How to request insecure SSL with TIdHTTP?

Tags: delphi, indy10, idhttp

I need to use `TIdHTTP` to request an HTTPS URL for an IP address on an SSL connection, so certificate validation will fail (if the peer even has a cert).

curl has the `-insecure` parameter and it works just fine, but I can't find anything in `TIdHTTP` to accomplish the same thing.

```
SSESocket := TIdHTTP.Create;
SSESocket.Request.Accept := 'text/event-stream';
SSESocket.Request.CacheControl := 'no-store';
SSESocket.Get('https://'+Host+'/eventstream/clip/v2', SSEventStream);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, and then you can set the IOHandler's `SSLOptions.VerifyMode` property to `[]` and its `SSLOptions.VerifyDepth` property to 0.

```
SSESocket := TIdHTTP.Create;

// add this ...
SSEIO := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(SSESocket);
SSEIO.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
SSEIO.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
SSEIO.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
SSEIO.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
SSESocket.IOHandler := SSEIO;
//

SSESocket.Request.Accept := 'text/event-stream';
SSESocket.Request.CacheControl := 'no-store';
SSESocket.Get('https://'+Host+'/eventstream/clip/v2',SSEventStream);
```

In your example, `TIdHTTP` is implicitly creating an internal `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` with default settings for you.

You can optionally also assign a handler to the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnVerifyPeer` event and have it return `True` to accept the server's certificate, regardless of whether OpenSSL would normally reject it.